# How to determine what is using this AWS network interface?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I am trying to determine what is using a network interface. It is not being used by any of the instances, NAT gateways, or elastic IPs that are in my account. It shows as

[image]

The instance section doesn't list the instance ID, but it does list an Instance Owner that is not my own account:

[image]

How can I find more details on what is using this network interface?  I didn't see any other details when fetching info using an API call either.  I wonder if perhaps this was used in the past by some account to which I had a peering connection, but when I checked just now there are no peering connections with the same owner as I see listed as Instance Owner for this network interface.  It shows "in-use" so I want to know what is using it--how can I find that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found from [this article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/requester-managed-eni.html) that

> **Requester-managed**: Indicates whether the network interface is managed by AWS.
>
> A requester-managed network interface is a network interface that an
> AWS service creates in your VPC on your behalf. The network interface
> is associated with a resource for another service, such as a DB
> instance from Amazon RDS, a NAT gateway, or an interface VPC endpoint
> from AWS PrivateLink.

In my case it was showing true for Requester Managed, and the description listed an ARN.  I could see that it was an ECS attachment ARN, so I was able to browse through the tasks in my ECS clusters (which run on AWS-managed Fargate) until I found one that matched the ENI.